Time resolution with dataset
Suppose I have one dataset which every point (means every row) is per 15 minutes, but my requirements is time resolution of an hour.
If I use the dataset which is time resolution of 15 minutes, would I get same result as of an hour? Or how to deal with this situation?

Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/46619/1794, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/130155/8560, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/653560/2921.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

If you use the 15-minute dataset without aggregation to hourly, the results will be at a higher resolution, and therefore potentially more granular or noisy.
Aggregating to hourly data will give you a smoother and less noisy view that might miss some finer details. You should determine what kind of information you want to retain and how best to summarize the data to an hourly level such as mean, sum, max/min, etc. The aggregation method can introduce bias if not chosen carefully. For example, using the mean for non-normal data or highly skewed data could misrepresent the hourly values.
